# Losing user input data due to heroku databse refresh (django backend)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, heroku

So I made a django app and deployed it using **Heroku** - with s3 for file uploads and whitenoise for static files. I use the admin page to add updates to the displayed sections, like new blog entries (for example or comments).

The problem is that **any database update using the admin page stays for a day at most and then refreshes, going back to the previous state** and making me lose all the new data.

I have tried some stuff, but I am totally out of my depth here. I even tried pulling the changes made back into my local copy and pushing again to repository but it shows no changes. Is it something to do with how Django takes in user input? If anyone could help me that would be amazing. If you guys need any code please tell me.

Comment: See if this helps: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: do you use sqllite ?